# Google Groups sends valid emails to spam / moderation from within our domain

Tags: google-groups, google-workspace-for-business, permissions

How can I adjust the settings so all the users within our google groups domain have their messages approved to go through?

Recently it seems the spam/moderation filter has been much more aggressive, stopping lots of messages from people within our company who routinely post to our internal mailing lists. I want to whitelist all people with our domain to automatically have their posts go through. Even my posts are getting stopped and I am the site admin/ list owners. This over aggressive filtering seems to be new.

Is there a way / what is the way to configure the overall group or all of my groups to all everyone from our company (so within our domain) to have their messages automatically whitelisted to go through?

On the permissions setting for "Post" it already shows:

```
All members of the group, All organization members
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to head to your advanced Gmail settings and [customise spam filter settings](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2368132). From here you can create a rule that does these two things.

- Be more aggressive for more stringent filtering of bulk email.
- Bypass mail sent from your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Each Google Group has a toggle in settings to configure spam filtering called ["Spam message handling"](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/2464926?hl=en). Mailbox-level spam filtering will still apply on any users who receive email from the Group.

If this doesn't work or you need more fine-grain control, try adding a [Content Compliance](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1346934?hl=en) rule in the Admin Panel for the affected Groups to not mark messages as spam. I would try to avoid inherently trusting any internal mail if possible, as it's a security risk